# pandas check condition in one column and populate data in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as below:

```
        State       Time           
        Approved    15 hours    
        Approved    NaT      
        Rejected    NaT
```

I want some sort of logic to check values in state column. 
If the value is "Rejected" and Time value is "NaT" then in the new column replace it with N/A. 
If the value is "Approved" and Time value is "NaT" then in the new column replace it with "error".

The final result should look something like this:

```
        State   Time           Final
        Approved    15 hours    15 hours
        Approved    NaT        error
        Rejected    NaT         N/A
```

In short I want to be able to run comparison(if/else/switch kind of thing) on various data columns in a dataframe and populate value in a column in the same dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you need to apply multiple condition use [`np.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
m1 = (df['State'] == 'Rejected') & (df['Time'] == 'NaT')
m2 = (df['State'] == 'Approved') & (df['Time'] == 'NaT')

df['final'] = np.select(condlist=[m1,m2],
                        choicelist=['N/A','error'],
                        default=df['Time'])
print(df)
```

```
 State          Time     final
0  Approved  15 hours  15 hours
1  Approved       NaT     error
2  Rejected       NaT       N/A
```

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize `numpy.where()` that can encode values into a column you describe. The example below utilizes a nested `If then..` statement

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'State' : ['Approved','Approved','Rejected'],
        'Time' : ['15 hours','NaT','NaT'] }

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['Final'] = np.where((df['State'] == 'Rejected') & (df['Time'] == 'NaT'), 'N/A',
                  np.where((df['State'] == 'Approved') & (df['Time'] == 'NaT'), 'error',df['Time']))

df
```

This outputs:

```
State      Time     Final
Approved   15 hours 15 hours
Approved   NaT      error
Rejected   NaT      N/A
```